How can I create an Azure alert rule to trigger when a quota in API Management is reached?
I want to create an alert rule to trigger when an API is called x number of times within a month. This is the Kusto Query (KQL) that I designed to get the number of requests:
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceId has "/subscriptions/000-000-000-000/resourceGroups/shared-prd-rg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/customer-apim"
| where apiId_s has "ApiName"
| where TimeGenerated >= startofmonth(now()) and TimeGenerated < now()
| count

And this is the table that is returned:

So I want to see an alert when the count of the query is above a threshold, say 1000.
The problem is that the result of the query is interpreted in a time series. Where I want it just to trigger when a threshold is reached without looking to the relavance in time. The time component is already in de Kusto Query.
How do I do that?


I want to see an alert when the count of the query is above a threshold, say 1000:

You can add count > 1000 (required threshold) and execute the below query to achieve the expected results.
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceId contains "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimjah"
| where TimeGenerated >= startofmonth(now()) and TimeGenerated < now()
|Count | where Count > 1000 //(Modify it based on the requirement)


Once it is done, add a new alert rule as shown below.

Now create a Custom log search signal with your query and add a threshold 1000 under alert logic to create an alert.


Then you need to click on Review + create and the rule will trigger an email successfully.
